Tamagui Popover not aligning correctly under my Input on React Native Android
I'm working on a React Native project using Tamagui for UI components. I'm having trouble getting a Popover to align correctly under a ControlledInput component which exists in a Dialog. Here's a simplified version of my current code:
<Popover
  size="$3"
  open={suggestionsOpen}
  onOpenChange={setSuggestionsOpen}
  placement="bottom-start"
  offset={{ mainAxis: 4 }}
>
  <Popover.Anchor>
    <ControlledInput
      control={control}
      name="name"
      label="Item name"
      inputProps={{
        onChangeText: onChangeSearchTerm,
        onFocus: () => {
          setSuggestionsOpen(true);
        },
        onLayout: ({ nativeEvent }) => {
          inputLayoutRef.current = nativeEvent.layout;
        },
      }}
    />
  </Popover.Anchor>
  {searchLineItems && searchLineItems.length > 0 && (
    <Popover.Content
      px={0}
      py={0}
      elevate
      width={inputLayoutRef.current?.width || 0}
      borderWidth={1}
      borderColor="$outlineColor"
      borderRadius="$3"
      disableFocusScope
      top={Platform.OS === 'android' '107%' : 0} <-- added this
    >
      {/* Popover content */}
    </Popover.Content>
  )}
</Popover>

The issue is that the Popover content is not aligning correctly under the ControlledInput. I've tried adjusting the placement and offset props, but it doesn't seem to help.
What I've Tried:

Adjusting the placement prop
Using the usePopoverContext hook
Added position: relative in the parent of the Popovers and Dialogs

This weirdly only happens on Android, not iOS.
How can I ensure that the Tamagui Popover content aligns correctly under the ControlledInput? Are there any specific Tamagui props or techniques I should be using to achieve this?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
